# Как сделать фон прозрачным?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Вот есть код http://jsfiddle.net/fymczv5v/

Тут при наведении происходит затухание картинки от краёв, но после неё остаётся чёрный фон, как сделать, чтобы этого не было и оставался только тот фон, который применён ко всему документу?

Comment: А где код-то?

Comment: Упс) поправил, забыл нажать кнопку Save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут не затухание картинки, а наложение слоя с однородным фоном на картинку происходит и плавное отображение этого слоя при клике на картинку. Прозрачность картинки не изменяется. Цвет фона этого слоя подстроить автоматически под цвет фона страницы не получится. Подумай, как изменять прозрачность непосредственно картинки.

Comment: Да в том то и проблема, что просто прозрачность, она же идёт сразу на весь элемент, а надо чтобы с двух сторон от краёв к центру...
я так понимаю, в моём случае не реально исправить это?

Comment: Можно придумать что-то, например, с масштабированием масок прозрачности -webkit-mask-image. Т.е. создать большую маску и плавно уменьшать ее, тем самым уменьшая видимое пространство изображения. Вот примеры движения http://css-tricks.com/webkit-image-wipes/ Но работать будет в Chrome и Safari и то не совсем одинаково.